# Unable to pull data from importhtml function in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I used the following two formulas to get data from the **related query table/list** of the Google Trends webpage but it doesn't give any result. Any idea why? and how can I get this to work? Thanks

```
=importhtml("https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=now%207-d&q=bob", "list", 1)
=importhtml("https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=now%207-d&q=bob", "table", 1)
```

Comment: I think your formula is correct. You can check this article that shares same implementation regarding [Google Sheets’ ImportHTML function to display data](https://support.geckoboard.com/hc/en-us/articles/206260188-Use-Google-Sheets-ImportHTML-function-to-display-data-in-Geckoboard).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With the link you provided, I tried running the code in chrome console but it did not output index number. The only thing I got is blank tables. Appreciate if you could help me with this.